# How to prevent ✳ symbol converting to emoji

Tags: javascript, typescript, unicode, emoji, converters

I have a problem where my ✳ (Eight-Spoked Asterisk) symbol is converting to emoji on iOS/android devices..

[https://hotemoji.com/eight-spoked-asterisk-emoji.html#:~:text=%E2%9C%B3%EF%B8%8F%20Meaning%20%E2%80%93%20Eight%2DSpoked%20Asterisk,a%20list%20as%20bullet%20points](https://hotemoji.com/eight-spoked-asterisk-emoji.html#:%7E:text=%E2%9C%B3%EF%B8%8F%20Meaning%20%E2%80%93%20Eight%2DSpoked%20Asterisk,a%20list%20as%20bullet%20points).

Can somebody help me on what to do to prevent convertion of normal symbol ✳ to emoji asterisk! I am working with react/typescript.

Example:

I want 1234 ✳✳✳✳ ✳✳✳✳ 5678 - this is fine on desktop

I dont want 1234 1234 ✳️✳️✳️✳️ ✳️✳️✳️✳️ 5678 - this happens on ios/android

Thanks

EDIT - Function that does replacement:

```
export const hideDigits = (value: string) => {
const parsedValue = value.slice(0, 4) + value.slice(4, value.length -4).replace(/\d/g,'\u2733') + value.slice(value.length -4);
return (
    normalizeVoucherCode(parsedValue)
);
```

};

Comment: Could you show us the function that replaces the numbers?

Comment: Added in main post! but basically: .replace(/\d/g,'\u2733')

Comment: As a workaround you could maybe simply use a different asterisk character?!
There are several variants of the asterisk: https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/asterisk

Comment: Why not use `*` instead of `✳`?

Comment: That's really weird, the asterisk has a code 0x2733 while the emoji has 0x2733FE0F. There's a `FE0F` more. I'm curious to know why

Comment: What if the font hasn't the character, and the operating system replaces it with an emoji? That's not documented though

Comment: I've read some specs and I think that this could work: `replace(/\d/g,'\u2733FEOE')`

Comment: I tried but it doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: @CristianTraìna `\u{2733fe0e}` maybe?  **EDIT:** That doesn't work, and attempting to generate `0xfe0e` gives a malformed character error. It looks like it's a [variation selector](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe0e/index.htm) which seems to define how something is rendered.

Comment: @Emanresua yes I forgot brackets. `fe0e` following an unicode character should force the text representation, while `fe0f` should force the emoji one

Comment: Like, I tried going to [this converted](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) and in the second box I typed `%u2733%uFE0E` and the text representation appeared, then I typed `%u2733%uFE0F` and the emoji representation appeared

Comment: .replace(/\d/g,'\u{2733}\u{FE0E}') I tried this but it doesnt work hmmm

Comment: Codepoint `️U+FE0F` is [Variation Selector-16](https://emojipedia.org/variation-selector-16/)… Read https://emojipedia.org/eight-spoked-asterisk/ as well…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this for anyone who is wondering!

```
//Force ✳︎ to never be parsed as emoji with variation selector \u{FE0E}!
const textSymbol = '\u{2733}\u{FE0E}';
```